# How to convert TCHAR to double visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, tchar

I want to convert tchar* variable to double for my project. How can i do that?

```
TCHAR *t = _T("1000.99");
```

Comment: Windows 95 was released exactly 20 years ago. Do you still need to support non-Unicode systems? Because if you only support Windows XP or newer, just use `L"1000.99"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [_tcstod()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab(v=VS.100).aspx) to convert TCHAR to double.

```
TCHAR *t = _T("1000.99");
LPTSTR endPtr;
double dValue = _tcstod(t, &endPtr);
```